# gulp-less task exits with zero on invalid styles

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-less

Firstly, here is **a repo with very simple example of my problem**: https://github.com/nkoder/example-of-gulp-less-zero-exit-on-error

I want to define gulp build pipeline which fails on any error. This pipeline would be used in automated process (eg. Continuous Integration) so I need the build command to return non-zero exit code on failure. It works for me with invalid Jade templates or non-passing tests run with Karma.

The problem is when I use `gulp-less` to prepare CSS from LESS. Whenever I add any pipeline step after `gulp-less` execution, all errors are "consumed" and the whole task exits with 0. But it shouldn't.

- The first question is: **How to force `wrong` task to fail with non-zero exit code?** (solved, see answer below)
- The second question is: **Why `error` event emitted in `less()` call followed by piped stream is not making a whole task to return non-zero exit code?** Non-zero is returned in some other similar cases, eg. in Jade or ESLint failure. (not solved yet)

Versions:

- node 5.11.0
- npm 3.8.6
- gulp 3.9.1
- gulp-less 3.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Listen for the [`error` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_error_1) and then exit the process explicitly:

```
gulp.task('wrong', function () {
  return gulp
    .src('invalid-styles.less')
    .pipe(less().on('error', function(error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      process.exit(1);
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('generated-styles.css'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution!   
I'm not a big fan of calling `process.exit(...)` explicitly but if it is the only way to have `less()` failing properly, then OK.